# Exception while Glassfish server started

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

Why I am having this messages down each time I start GlassFish 4.1 in my console. My IDE is Eclipse Oxygen. My JDK is java 8?

```
2018-05-01T23:39:53.272+0000|Grave: Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class of size 7264
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:358)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 6):

You are using log4j2 2.9 (or later) which is in multi-release jar format and contains java 9 specific .class files (like the mentioned `META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class`) that the old asm library included in glassfish 4.1 cannot understand.
Try to switch to log4j2 2.8

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to try it. But how to switch to log4j2 2.8? Can you please direct me?

Comment: You can download log4j2 2.8 at http://archive.apache.org/dist/logging/log4j/2.8/ - just replace the JARs you used with those from the 2.8 release.